# The error when publishing a shiny app

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I want to publish my shiny app. For this I created an account in https://www.shinyapps.io/
Then, in RStudio, I go to `Tools->Shiny Apps->Publish Apps` and paste the token, account and secret information.
Finally, I get the error:

```
Error: /v1/users/current/ 426 - shinyapps package out of date.
 To update visit: https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps
```

[image]

When I try to install "shinyapps", the following message occurs:

```
install.packages("shinyapps")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

Error in tools:::httpdPort <= 0L : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, please install **shinyapps** from https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps It is not a package on CRAN, so you cannot `install.packages()`.

Comment: Just a side note for others: Packages from github can by installed by using `devtools::install_github(repo)` and the package `devtools` is on CRAN, therefore it can be installed with `install.packages()`.